# How to add latest module in Opencart Version 2.0.0.0

Tags: opencart

How do I add latest module in Opencart Version 2.0.0.0 Home page? I try many but can not success.

Please help me .

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See this tutorials for set module in OpenCart 2.0 http://www.harnishdesign.net/blog/2014/10/09/how-to-set-layout-position-of-module-in-opencart-2-0/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module or extension and does not involve any programmatic problem. Such question should be asked at extension's dev support, OpenCart support or OpenCart Forums.

Answer (score 0):

Login Admin:
Step 1: Extentsions -> Module: 
Active module Lastest
Step 2: System -> Design -> Layout
Select Layout Home -> Edit
Add Module Lastet
Finish

Answer (score 0):

To add latest products on home page follow below steps,

1. In your Open Cart admin go to Extensions > Modules and click Install near to "Latest" module.
2. Click **Edit** button at the right near to Latest Module.
3. Enter Module Name as latest-product (put any name to recognize it).
4. Give limit,height,width.
5. Make Status as **Enabled**.
6. Click on save button.
7. Now Go to **System > Design > Layouts** and edit **Home** layout.
8. Choose **"Latest > latest-product"** for **Module** , select **Position** and give **Sort Order**.
9. Click on save button.

Comment: I have opencart 2.2 and a similar problem : New products are show in ALL layouts I add, but for homepage I get PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: in module/latest.tpl ...

Comment: Finally it was the problem of "latest.tpl" from the theme ::: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: module in public_html/catalog/view/theme/fashion/template/module/latest.tpl on line 3, 43, 52, 61